# Process state change from sleep to awake?

Tags: process, linux-kernel, operating-system

what should happen if the kernel attempts to awaken all process sleeping on an event, but no process are asleep on the event at the time of the wakeup

Please explain .

Comment: Please explain.  If some thread signals an event when nothing is waiting on it, nothing happens except that maybe the event gets set.   Don't really understand your question...

Comment: This question is there in the "THE DESIGN OF THE UNIX OPERATING SYSTEM" by Maurice J. Bach.  Also there was a mistake in my question i have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

If the kernel attempts to awaken all processes sleeping on an event, but no processes are asleep on the event at the time of the wakeup, essentially nothing happens. The wakeup call has no effect because there are no processes in a sleep state that need to be awakened1. This is because the system call for waking up processes only affects those that are currently in a waiting or sleeping state. If there are no such processes, the call will simply return without performing any action